# Problems launching blueprint Fi-Lab Cloud

Tags: fiware, filab

I need to launch a VM with Orion Context Broker and CEP in Fi-Lab. For this I clone a template with Orion and then I add a tier with CEP. Then I launch the blueprint instance, but always I have an error:

```
Success: Blueprint Instance FinalMachine status.

Description: Create environment FinalMachine

Status: ERROR

Error: Infrastructure error Error creating server: {"overLimit": {"message": "Quota exceeded: code=InstanceLimitExceeded", "code": 413, "retryAfter": 0}}
```

What is it happening??

**UPDATE**

An screenshot of my blueprint:
[image]

Another screenshot of my instance tab:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should check your available quotas. Do you have any other deployed VM or any other public IP consumed, apart from this blueprint template?

If you try to deploy a new VM, in the open windows in which you have to introduce the data of your new VM, you can see on the right the available resources for your user.

Comment: I have 3 MV: 1 stopped and 2 with status: ERROR. I can't delete these MV (I don't know why). I have only one public IP and at this moment it's free. (I update the question with a new picture)

Comment: Where can I see my quota available??

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the quota that you have available, you only need to launch a new instance.

[image]

On the bottom right you could see in this case the number of available instances, vcpus, disk and memory for that user, together with the resources that currently have used (dark grey) and the new resources to consume (green).

Comment: I have 0 availables. But I can't remove the VM that I don't need. Why I can't remove these??

Comment: In case that you cannot delete any resources due to some problems in the infrastructure, I recommend you to put an incidence in the corresponding channel. Send an email to fiware-lab-help@lists.fiware.org describing the problem, your username, the resource id and your project. It creates automatically a ticket that should be resolved in 2 days.

Comment: I think that it was a problem with the platform, but I don't remember. This questions is 9 months ago :(